# how to make entry widget in python tkinter respond on pressing a key

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So, I'm making this game on python, Tkinter, where when I click the button "get a word", the computer randomly gives me a 6-8 letter word, now after it gives a word, an entry widget comes. In that, I have to type words and letters that are there inside the word given to me by the computer, so the problem is that after I am done typing the word or letter that I see in the word I should press the "enter" key and the computer should get to know about it and see the text written in the entry widget and check if the thing I wrote is there in the word given, if it is there, it should tell True.
else it should say false

can someone help me with this

thankyou

Comment: You have to provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: We can't give you an answer until you show us your code. Also have you looked at `<tkinter.Entry>.get()`?

Comment: You can use `.bind('<event>', func)` to do this

Comment: its something like....

if key == "enter":

    <tkinter.Entry>.get()

but i dont know how to write that in tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def print_entry(event):
    print(variable.get())

root = tk.Tk()

variable = tk.StringVar(master=root)
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=variable)
entry.pack()
# <Return> is the "Enter" key on your keyboard
entry.bind("<Return>", print_entry)

root.mainloop()
```

It binds to `"<Return>"` and executes `print_entry`. In `print_entry` it just prints everything inside the `<tkinter.Entry>`

Comment: Ok so this does work but i need the text typed inside the entry widget to come inside a variable because that text i want to print it on the screen where you are palying the game

Comment: @vatsal Ok I changed it but you can always use `entry.get()` to get what is inside the `<tkinter.Entry>` so I can't find a reason for why you would be using a `tkinter.StringVar`